# Powershell Logging in to Google (web scraping)

Tags: powershell, authentication

I'm currently looking for a way to log in to google with Powershell, but everything I tie won't work

this is my current Code

```
$site = Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'https://accounts.google.com/_/lookup/accountlookup?hl=de&_reqid=572947&rt=j' -Method post -Body @{identifier = "MyEmail"; password = "MyPassword"}
```

and the response is:

```
    Invoke-WebRequest:
Line |
   2 |  $site = Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'https://accounts.google.com/_/lookup/ …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | )]}'
[[["er",null,null,null,null,403,null,null,null,7]
,["e",2,null,null,80]
]]
```

I tried a lot but still can't figure out why it doesn't work ???

Comment: Did you check some of the official Google APIs? Here is a GitHub repo: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples